# How to read or convert a binary data to file without reading from a physical address or before writing it in somewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I convert a base64 value to `byte[]` by `Convert.FromBase64String(..)`.My question is how can I convert or read the byte[] file in my C# code without downloading or reading it from a physical address. in fact I want to open this binary file on the fly and no reading from a physical place.
Can we do that?

**Edited (better question):**
`var binary = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);`
now I want to convert binary data to txt file and then read all data that there in txt file .
attachment property  is a txt file that I saved before in my table ...

Comment: What do you mean by "reading from a physical address"?

Comment: I meant that I want to open a binary data and convert it to TxT file (my binary data is a txt file that I attached in my table and ...) in my code . I want to read all data in txt file before download it

Comment: Even more confusing now. How can "binary data" be a text file? Which "table"? What do you "download" and from where? Sorry, this question does not make much sense to me in this form.

Comment: I convert a base64 value to byte in c# then. What is this base64 value ? A txt file (for example a sample.txt file ). I converted this base64 value to byte and I want to convert the byte value to sample.txt without downloading it . Why ? Coz I want to read some line in sample.txt but how can I read these line whereas my file value is a byte file in this time cuz I don't want download it.  This is my best to transfer..

Comment: So you want to undo the FromBase64String? Use [Convert.ToBase64String}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string). If this is not what you need, I tend to give up trying to understand the question.

Comment: No bro. I know how to convert and etc ... thanks for your notice